# mysqli_stmt::bind_param()Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with using `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables...

```
public function init($cards, $table, $seats) {
    $operation = $this->operation($table, $seats);
    return $this->insertCards($cards, $operation, count($cards));
}

public function operation($table, $seats) {
    $operation = "insert into ".$table."(";
    $values = "(";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($seats); $i++) {
        $operation .= " cardsSeat".$seats[$i].",";
        $values .= "?,";
    }
    $values .= "?,?,?)";
    $operation .= " flop, turn, river) values ".$values;

    return $operation;
}

public function insertCards($cards, $operation, $x) {
    $insertCards = $this->spojenie->prepare($operation);
    $refArray = array();
    foreach ($cards as $key => $value) {
        $refArray[$key] = &$cards[$key];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($insertCards, 'bind_param'), $refArray);

    $insertCards->execute();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors when Binding Params (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131297/errors-when-binding-params-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

- string types ("sss...");

  ```
  public function insertCards($cards, $operation, $x)
  {

      $types = "";
      foreach($cards as $value)
          $types .= "s";
      $cards = array_merge(array($types),$cards);
      $insertCards = $this->spojenie->prepare($operation);
      $refArray = array();
      foreach($cards as $key => $value) $refArray[$key] = &$cards[$key];
      call_user_func_array(array($insertCards, 'bind_param'), $refArray);



      $insertCards->execute();
      return true;
  }
  ```