# Updating records in bulk with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm aware this question has been asked severally but i am unable to find the solution I'm looking for. I have managed to upload CSV files to my database and managed to update them, however there is a limit to number of records i get to update which is 90 rows at most. I've tried uploading records with 400 records but it is unable to update this records. Size wise in the database it has consumed 180kb.

If the query is the issue please guide as any assistance will be appreciated

```
  echo  $query="SELECT  bankstatement.referenceno,bankstatement.debit,bankstatement.credit,bankstatement.status,cashbook.referenceno,
            cashbook.debit,cashbook.credit,cashbook.status
                FROM   bankstatement CROSS JOIN
                             cashbook
                            where '$bank' = '$cash' and cashbook.credit = bankstatement.debit and cashbook.debit = bankstatement.credit and bankstatement.status = '0' and cashbook.status = '0' ";

     echo   $res= mysqli_query($db,$query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ".mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);


        if($res){
        echo $change = "update bankstatement set status='1' where referenceno in($bank)";
        echo $change1 = "update cashbook set status='1' where referenceno in($cash)";


        echo mysqli_query($db,$change);
        echo mysqli_query($db,$change1);

echo "<script>
        alert('Success in Reconciling Process!!!');
        window.location.href='viewreconcile.php';
        </script>
        ";
    }else{
        echo "<script>
        alert('Error in Reconciling Process!!!');
        window.location.href='managereconcile.php';
        </script>
        ";
    }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: rewrite your query to use prepared statements please. Right now your application is too easily hacked.

Comment: What happens when you reach the limit? What error messages are logged? Sent back to your code?

Comment: @symcbean There's no error message it in fact shows a success message but no updating really occurs

Comment: Where, in the code above, do you check for the message?

Comment: @symcbean I've included the message code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just skip the first steps to check if there's a back account that hasn't had it's switches set, because your update statement will just update everything in the where in array.

I added the `where status='0'` statement to your update query to limit the update to the rows that actually need the update.

```
// The back account numbers to update
$bank_accounts= [000001, 0000002, 000003];
// adding fix from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527202/mysqli-stmtbind-paramnumber-of-elements-in-type-definition-string-doesnt-ma
$types = implode('', array_fill(0, count($bank_accounts), 's'));
$bank_accounts = array_merge([$types], $bank_accounts);

$to_prepare = [];
foreach($bank_accounts as $key => $value) {
   $to_prepare[$key] = &$bank_accounts[$key];
}

// Preparing the parameters for the prepared statement
$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($bank_accounts), '?'));


// Preparing the statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("update bankstatement 
                     set status='1' 
                     where 
                        status='0' 
                     and 
                        referenceno in($clause)
                     ");

// always check whether the prepare() succeeded 
if ($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error($db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  return;
}

// bind the bank accounts to the parameters
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $to_prepare );

// Update all the rows
$stmt->execute();
```

And this would work the same way for the cash query.

Comment: The array would hold the values that needed to be updated its just that after a certain number of values updating wouldn't occur. Thanks for the above solution

Comment: @SamuelJak still, your update value doesn't hold any values from your first select. Only the same parameters you used to filter the first result sets in the query.

Comment: I'm rather unfamiliar with prepared statements but I've managed to work with the above code but I'm getting the following error

*Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\wamp\www\BankRecon\recon.php on line 62`*
How do i sort this issue

Comment: @SamuelJak I forgot about that, yea you need to compile a second array that contains the references. I updated my answer. For extra info read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120822/mysqli-bind-param-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given

Comment: I'm getting more errors now especially in this line of code  below, i dont what i'm doing wrong as I've also followed the link you provided. Could it be something i did earlier

`call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $to_prepare );`

Comment: This is the error I'm now getting,kindly help in sorting this issue
*Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\wamp\www\BankRecon\recon1.php on line 67*

Comment: can you provide a `var_dump($clause, $bank_accounts(anonymised), $to_prepare(anonymised))` output, somewhere in a pastebin? also your query text you use in `$db->prepare`

Comment: The `$db->prepare` ive been using is the one you provided above and as for the query output is below:
[var_dump output]: https://pasteboard.co/HzqMQuv.png

Comment: @SamuelJak and the dump of the of the $bank_accounts and $to_prepare?

Comment: [bank_account dump]: https://pasteboard.co/HzrtPcAs.png
[to_prepare dump]: https://pasteboard.co/HzruRx8.png

Comment: @SamuelJak I updated my code, see line 3 and 4 and the question I linked in the comment

Comment: Hi sorry to bother but its still giving me this same error
*Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\wamp\www\BankRecon\recon1.php on line 73*

[New_vardump]: https://pasteboard.co/HzyzszI.png

Comment: Hmm, i followed the example, then I'm not sure what to do now. Maybe try using PDO.

Comment: I'll try out PDO. This is the whole code i'm using to compare from two tables with checkbox arrays, if there is a problem with it i'd really appreciate since you've helped me out last few days.

[comparison_code]: https://pastebin.com/rpFN6xgy

Comment: @SamuelJak only thing I can think of is that you do `$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($bank_accounts), '?')` before merging the types into the $bank_accounts. but that's it really...

Comment: Hey i got the code to work out over the weekend, thanks for the help